# AutoAdminLogin vs user with blank password

Tags: winlogon, mdt

I'm in a scenario (MDT) where I've got a single local user with a blank password, and the built-in Administrator account is set to auto-login via the HKLM...\AutoAdminLogon,etc. registry keys.

If I restart the machine during the MDT task sequence, the local user with blank password will login upon restart. I'd like to better understand this.

Am I dealing with a race condition in terms of which account gets logged in? I can find lots of info about the AutoAdminLogon registry keys, but can't find anything about how/why the blank password user auto-logins. I'd actually be happy to rely on the behavior I'm seeing if it is something "guaranteed" by how windows works.

I'm looking for any info on how blank password autologin works or thoughts on why it wins over AutoAdminLogon.

Answer (score 0):

I learned a couple things.

First, AutoAdminLogon actually wins versus account with blank password. I was seeing evidence to the contrary because I had a step in my MDT task sequence that was inadvertently disabling the account set for AutoAdminLogon.

Second, I believe it is behavior like that being complained about [here](https://superuser.com/questions/952868/can-i-disable-auto-logon-on-windows-10-home) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/947040/how-to-prevent-automatic-login-of-the-last-user-in-windows-10) that covers the auto-login behavior of windows 10.

Unbeknownst to me, it was this auto-login last user behavior that was actually keeping my task sequence from failing even though I had unintentionally disabled the AutoAdminLogon account during the task sequence.